# Is there any “approximate or probabilistic” password authentication method?

Tags: authentication, passwords

I understand that the password-based authorization check procedure requires that you enter a password that is *correct, that is, does not allow even a single bit difference*.

Suddenly I have this thought.

---

**[System A]** For password-based authorization system A, let's assume that the password is 256bit.

And it always asks for the correct password for permission verification.

The probability of successful authorization with a brute-force attack on system A is **1/(2^256)**.

---

**[System B]** In the case of other authorization system B, we will assume that the password is (264 == 256+8)bit.

Instead, it is assumed that system B **allows a difference of less than 2 bit among 264-bit passwords.**
The probability of correcting the password with a brute-force attack on system B is **(1+264)/(2^264)**.

I think there is very little difference between System A and B.

The probability of a successful brute-force attack for both is about 8.Xe-78.

---

If so, (though it may be unrealistic), let's assume that the password storage medium is unstable on a certain **system C**.

That is, **an n-bit flip (n < 2) may occur in the password during the authorization process.** (Assume that error-correcting is also impossible.)

In this system, if strict authorization is applied like System A, even a user with a true password may not be authorized.

So, I think it would be good to apply probabilistic authorization(like system B) for system C.

---

I wonder if there is actually such a probabilistic authorization theory or techniques.

Comment: For passwords, brute force is the wrong attack scenario. Passwords are not uniformly generated but usually chosen by humans. And for dictionary attacks, allowing small variations might have a much larger impact. Thus your assumption about A and B having the same security is most likely wrong - but it's hard to prove, because it depends a lot on the dictionary and the password requirements.

Comment: Facial recognition is approximate. But unlike password, it's not something you know, but instead, it's something that you are.

Comment: This answer might be relevant  https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/93615/assuming-biometric-data-could-be-private-can-it-be-a-key/

Comment: I see! Thanks for your reply :)